# Test a collection is Many to many or many to one

Tags: nhibernate

Is there anyway for me to test if a collection is a many to many or many to one relationship from the session.

I have got as far as using the

SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(type)

which gives the PropertyTypes collection but this doesn't distinguish between many to many and many to one where as one to many is catered for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code, will iterate `TheEntity` property names, to find the mapped collections. Then, it will ask for Collection persister and get informed about One-to-Many or Many-to-Many

```
var persister = factory
    .GetClassMetadata(typeof(TheEntity)) as AbstractEntityPersister;

// iterate property names
foreach (var propertyName in persister.PropertyNames)
{
    // find type
    var index = persister.GetPropertyIndex(propertyName);
    var propertyType = persister.PropertyTypes[index];

    // check if it is collection
    if (!propertyType.IsCollectionType)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // the Role is
    // the Entity type Name & the Collection name
    var roleName = persister.Name + "." + propertyName;

    // the Abstract collection persister
    var collectionPersister = factory
        .GetCollectionMetadata(roleName) as AbstractCollectionPersister;

    // here we go:
    var isManyToMany = collectionPersister.IsManyToMany;
    var isOneToMany = collectionPersister.IsOneToMany;

}
```

*Note: I guess that in your question the Many-to-One (which is the reference not collection mapping) should be `One-to-Many`*

Comment: Thanks very much, so close but you just gave me the xtra push i needed!

Comment: Also is there any way to get hold of the child collection property name from the many to many relationship?

Comment: If you are asking, how to get a value of attribute *class* from this statement: `<many-to-many class="ReferencedEntityClassName" column="ReferencedEntityClassNameId" />`, then it is available here: `collectionPersister.ElementNodeName`