# Exploring nhibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

A code generator needs to extract and generate some metadata from nhibernate mappings, I am wondering how nhibernate store relations.

For many to one relation how the other side stored (one to one part)

Domain model:

```
public class Person
{
  public Detail {get;set;}
}

public class Detail 
{
  public Person {get;set;}
}
```

Traversing map:

```
PersistentClass map = _config.GetClassMapping(typeof(Person));
Property prop = map.GetProperty("Detail");

// how to find Associated Property (I.E. 'Detail.Person')
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration, and later `ISessionFactory` build from it, are keeping information about persisters. They could represent entities or collections.

Here we can see what we could get about any persisted class:

- [How do you get the database column name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155058/1679310)

The class persister:

```
var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
var factory = ... // Get your ISessionFactory
var persister = factory.GetClassMetadata(entityType) as AbstractEntityPersister;
```

And we also can observe collection persisters

- [Test a collection is Many to many or many to one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18814668/1679310)

the collection persister:

```
// the Abstract collection persister
var collectionPersister = factory
    .GetCollectionMetadata(roleName) as AbstractCollectionPersister;

// here we go:
var isManyToMany = collectionPersister.IsManyToMany;
var isOneToMany = collectionPersister.IsOneToMany;
```

So, in general, what is mapped, it is represented as persister. Hope it helps

EXTEND, find out `one-to-one`

Based on the stuff above, the explicit search for `one-to-one` could be like:

```
var persister = factory.GetClassMetadata(entityType) as AbstractEntityPersister;
var propertyNameList = persister.PropertyNames;

foreach (var propertyName in propertyNameList)
{
    // many info is in collections, so we need to know the index
    // of our property
    var index = persister.GetPropertyIndex(propertyName);

    // with index, we can work with the mapped type
    var type = persister.PropertyTypes[index];

    // if the type is OneToOne... we can observe
    if(type is NHibernate.Type.OneToOneType)
    {
        Console.Write(type.IsAssociationType);
        Console.Write(type.IsAnyType);
        Console.Write(type.IsMutable);
        Console.Write(type.IsCollectionType);
        Console.Write(type.IsComponentType);
        Console.Write(type.ReturnedClass);
        ...
        // many other interesting and useful info could be revealed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure about one to one relations.

Comment: Not fully sure what you are searching for... but with persisters as shown above, we can investigate a lot. And in fact, as you said, I do use these *meta* to build my own - upper layer Metadata... hope this helps

Comment: Thanks again, I have made a change to question.